# Unknown problem in Python. Printing does not work and files are not saved correctly

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

**When I try to write something, such as variables, the code is renamed to the file name on the computer.**

For example, if I write:

```
a = 20
f = 15

print(a+f)
```

then the code file will automatically be renamed to the first line, i.e. "*a = 20*"

**Then, when I try to run the code, the program outputs nothing but "Python" and some incomprehensible words.**

What could it be related to?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXiaa.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68zJK.png)

I installed the latest version of Visual Stuio Code with Python, they are new, so there should be no problems. But this time it went wrong.

***After reinstalling the program, the problem remains.***

Comment: as for the tab handle title bit, that's just what happens when the file hasn't been given a path to be saved to (working as intended if you haven't saved the file anywhere yet). It's also default behaiour that the template file name when you save a new file that hasn't been saved before is the first line of code.

Comment: As for the code running part, are you using the Code Runner extension?

Comment: Yes, I install the Python and Code Runner extensions in Visual Sutio code every time.

Comment: It is strange, for each new project I create a separate folder on the second hard drive. Again, I don't understand why this problem appeared, since I did what I did and always with the same sequence without a single error.

Comment: try the IDLE editor and report what you get back please.

Comment: don't use `untitled` files, save the file before running, don't use Code Runner, read the VSC Python doc pages, use launch configs

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if there is no special requirement, please do not use *Code Runner* to run the script, using the official extension [**Python**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) is a better choice.

In addition, the dot on your file label means that you have not saved the file, you can add the following setting to enable automatic saving in the settings.

```json
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
```

You may have created the file using the following method. `File --> New File... --> Python File`. At this time, the file has not been named, also not saved. You can see that there is no such file in the resource manager list at this time.

[image]

So the file label shows the first line of codes. *This is a feature of vscode*, you can refer to this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/37414). And because the file has not been saved, there will be problems executing the script.

You can rename the script file directly (<kbd>F2</kbd>), or vscode will remind you to name the file when saving. Another way to create a file is to right click and choose `New File...`, enter filename and end with `.py` extension.

[image]